# How can separated my ObjectID? (using mongodb especially in relationships)

Tags: javascript

[image]My ObjectID has seperated like in Command Prompt like this one

```
 "tchStudents" : [
            ObjectId("616450eeecf687bc5f59fac2"),
            ObjectId("61645108ecf687bc5f59fac4"),
            ObjectId("616451a8ecf687bc5f59fac8")
 ]
```

but if we fetch the data and display on the browser, it just like this

```
616450eeecf687bc5f59fac261645108ecf687bc5f59fac4616451a8ecf687bc5f59fac8
```

Can I use .split or .slice
Thank you for helping out

Comment: What debugging have you done to figure out how the data ends up like this in the first place? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use match with `/.{1,24}/g` regex

```js
let str = "616450eeecf687bc5f59fac261645108ecf687bc5f59fac4616451a8ecf687bc5f59fac8"
let arr = str.match(/.{1,24}/g);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: When Im edit or save the data with array it goes like that picture above

Comment: I think your problem is on html maybe you can put some of your code to show how you pass data to html or EJS

Comment: Im using React Hooks for this one and Nodejs Mongo